# MAX(Column) returns me a wrong value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the maximum invoice number from my invoice table where it returns the following when I select all records where you can clearly see the maximum invoice no as "10".

```
select * from invoice
```

[image]

But when I query for

```
select MAX(invoice_number) as maxinv from invoice
```

It returns me "9". Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Is the datatype of that column numeric or varchar? That result suggests it's being treated as text rather than a number

Comment: is that column `invoice_number` a char type?

Comment: Please check your data type it may possible that you are using varchar instead of int

Comment: Yes you are correct its in VARCHAR, what I can do to retrieve the correct value without changing the datatype?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** store numbers in `VARCHAR` columns. Just don't (and don't store dates in `VARCHAR` columns either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This situation can occur if your `invoice_number` is stored as a text column e.g. `varchar(10)`. In that case, based on alphabetical order, 9 will be the maximum value.

Ideally, you should be storing values on which you want to perform numerical operations as numeric datatypes e.g. `int`. However, if for some reason you cannot change column datatype, you can try casting the column before applying `MAX`, like so:

```
select max (convert(invoice_number, signed integer)) as maxinv from invoice
```

NOTE: I specifically mention **"values on which you want to perform numerical operations"** because there are cases where the input text is entirely numeric, such as phone numbers or perhaps credit card numbers, but there is no scenario in which you would want to add 2 phone numbers, or take the square root of a credit card number. Such values should be stored as text.

Comment: Yes you are correct, what I can do to retrieve the correct value without changing the datatype?

Answer (score 3):

It happens because your column is a `VARCHAR`, try to cast it to `UNSIGNED`:

```
select MAX(CAST(invoice_number AS UNSIGNED)) as maxinv from invoice
```

As Joshi noticed, if you have negative values you can use `SIGNED`

```
select MAX(CAST(invoice_number AS SIGNED)) as maxinv from invoice
```

Comment: If the table contains a negative number, then it will not give correct result. For example, it will return some random number. So better to use 'SIGNED'.

Comment: @Joshi I supposed that invoice number could not be a negative number, since well, does it make sense to have a negative invoice number? But you made a good point, it could be also the case, I will add you solution to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, Invoice number should not be negative, but SQL query should be correct for any case. Thank you for adding on to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pseudo code, try and see it.

`SELECT MAX(CAST(invoice_number AS SIGNED)) from invoice`.